# Как в vk_api выбрать тип загружаемого документа?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, fileupload

В общем, мне нужно загрузить документ .txt в ВК и сделать так, чтобы этот документ можно было искать через поиск по документам, т.е. при ручном добавлении документа есть выбор типа документа из 4 предложенных, а именно:

1. Личный документ (недоступен через поиск)
2. Учебный документ
3. Книга
4. Другой документ (желательно именно этот тип)

Я разобрался как загружать документ через библиотеку vk_api, там всё довольно просто, код приложен снизу. Но я не могу найти в этой библиотеке выбор документа, в функции document() есть аргумент doc_type, но я ни где не нашел что это вообще за doc_type и какие параметры он принимает, пробовал и числа ему передавать, как написано в документации от вк - [Ссылка](https://vk.com/dev/objects/doc) и строки вида "text", "doc", "other" и т.д., ничего не получается. На сколько я понимаю эту библиотеку не обновляли долгое время, а раньше у ВК не было этого выбора типа документа, но что теперь делать? Любому совету буду благодарен!

```
import vk_api
login = 'some_login'
password = 'some_password'
filename = 'some_file.txt'
title = 'some_title'
tags = open('tags.txt').read()

def doc_upload():
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)
    vk_session.auth()
    upload = vk_api.VkUpload(vk_session)
    upload.document(filename, title, tags)

doc_upload()
```

Answer (score 0):

Параметр `doc_type` метода VkUpload.document - цифровое значение, которое и позволяет определить искомый вами "тип документа".

Список возможных значений указан на [странице описания объекта "Документ"](https://vk.com/dev/objects/doc)(поле type):

1. текстовые документы
2. архивы
3. gif
4. изображения
5. аудио
6. видео
7. электронные книги
8. неизвестно

Comment: Я же написал что я пробовал передавать в этот аргумент числа, даже ссылку ту же оставил